# How to build dynamic query with Where and OR using Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, asp.net-web-api2

I hope somebody can guide and help me with this. We have an inherited project that uses `ExpressionHelper` class. Basically, this Expression Helper will return an `IQueryable` that build a dynamic query base on the search term that the user provided.

For example, I have the below code where I pass 2 search terms.

```
    IQueryable<UserEntity> modifiedQuery = _uow.UserRepository.GetAll();;

    var searchTerms = new List<SearchTerm>
    {
        new SearchTerm { Name = "FirstName", Operator = "eq", Value = "Bob" },
        new SearchTerm { Name = "FirstName", Operator = "eq", Value = "John" }
    };

    foreach (var searchTerm in searchTerms)
    {
        var propertyInfo = ExpressionHelper
            .GetPropertyInfo<TEntity>(searchTerm.EntityName ?? searchTerm.Name);

        var obj = ExpressionHelper.Parameter<TEntity>();

        var left = ExpressionHelper.GetPropertyExpression(obj, propertyInfo);
        var right = searchTerm.ExpressionProvider.GetValue(searchTerm.Value);
        var comparisonExpression = searchTerm.ExpressionProvider
            .GetComparison(left, searchTerm.Operator, right);

        // x => x.Property == "Value"
        var lambdaExpression = ExpressionHelper
            .GetLambda<TEntity, bool>(obj, comparisonExpression);

        // query = query.Where...
        modifiedQuery = ExpressionHelper.CallWhere(modifiedQuery, lambdaExpression);
    }
```

With the code above and using the below ExpressionHelper class, this generate the below SQL query when I check using `SQLProfiler`. Please notice the `AND` in the query. What I actually what is `OR`.

**Constructed QUERY in SQL Profiler**

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    FROM [dbo].[tblUser] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Conatact1] = N'Bob') AND ([Extent1].[Contact2] = N'John')
```

**ExpressionHelper.cs**

```
public static class ExpressionHelper
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo LambdaMethod = typeof(Expression)
        .GetMethods()
        .First(x => x.Name == "Lambda" && x.ContainsGenericParameters && x.GetParameters().Length == 2);

    private static MethodInfo[] QueryableMethods = typeof(Queryable)
        .GetMethods()
        .ToArray();

    private static MethodInfo GetLambdaFuncBuilder(Type source, Type dest)
    {
        var predicateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(source, dest);
        return LambdaMethod.MakeGenericMethod(predicateType);
    }

    public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<T>(string name)
        => typeof(T).GetProperties()
        .Single(p => p.Name == name);

    public static ParameterExpression Parameter<T>()
        => Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

    public static MemberExpression GetPropertyExpression(ParameterExpression obj, PropertyInfo property)
        => Expression.Property(obj, property);

    public static LambdaExpression GetLambda<TSource, TDest>(ParameterExpression obj, Expression arg)
        => GetLambda(typeof(TSource), typeof(TDest), obj, arg);

    public static LambdaExpression GetLambda(Type source, Type dest, ParameterExpression obj, Expression arg)
    {
        var lambdaBuilder = GetLambdaFuncBuilder(source, dest);
        return (LambdaExpression)lambdaBuilder.Invoke(null, new object[] { arg, new[] { obj } });
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> CallWhere<T>(IQueryable<T> query, LambdaExpression predicate)
    {
        var whereMethodBuilder = QueryableMethods
            .First(x => x.Name == "Where" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2)
            .MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(T) });

        return (IQueryable<T>)whereMethodBuilder
            .Invoke(null, new object[] { query, predicate });
    }

    public static IQueryable<TEntity> CallOrderByOrThenBy<TEntity>(
        IQueryable<TEntity> modifiedQuery,
        bool useThenBy,
        bool descending,
        Type propertyType,
        LambdaExpression keySelector)
    {
        var methodName = "OrderBy";
        if (useThenBy) methodName = "ThenBy";
        if (descending) methodName += "Descending";

        var method = QueryableMethods
            .First(x => x.Name == methodName && x.GetParameters().Length == 2)
            .MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(TEntity), propertyType });

        return (IQueryable<TEntity>)method.Invoke(null, new object[] { modifiedQuery, keySelector });
    }
}
```

I have hard time understanding on how the query was created and how do I change it to become `OR` in the created query.

Hope someone can guide me and point to the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: You should take some time to read official docs about expression trees. It's not a simple subject but you will probably wrap your head around after good understanding of expression trees. You can start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries

Comment: You'll have to rewrite the `ExpressionHelper.CallWhere`. It is using a "trick"... `Query.Where(A).Where(B)` is translated to `Query.Where(A && B)`. To use the `||` you'll have to write something to do it. And it gets more complex from here. To "merge" manually expressions (you want to merge A to B with ||) is a pain and you need what is called an "`ExpressionVisitor`"

Comment: @xanatos - thanks for your comment. I will try my best to understand that on how to implement it. but i'm still in the stage of absorbing what is actually happening in that code and how do i apply it in our current helper.

Comment: @xanatos thanks again! i will try to make this work because currently i'm stuck and i'm not progressing on my code updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to `SearchTerm` a new property (C# 6.0 syntax here):

```
    // This is quite wrong. We should have an enum here, but Operator is 
    // done as a string, so I'm maintaining the "style"
    // Supported LogicalConnector: and, or
    public string LogicalConnector { get; set; } = "and";
}
```

Then:

```
private static IQueryable<TEntity> BuildQuery<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> modifiedQuery, List<SearchTerm> searchTerms)
{
    Expression comparisonExpressions = null;

    var obj = ExpressionHelper.Parameter<TEntity>();

    foreach (var searchTerm in searchTerms)
    {
        var propertyInfo = ExpressionHelper
            .GetPropertyInfo<TEntity>(searchTerm.EntityName ?? searchTerm.Name);

        var left = ExpressionHelper.GetPropertyExpression(obj, propertyInfo);
        var right = searchTerm.ExpressionProvider.GetValue(searchTerm.Value);
        var comparisonExpression = searchTerm.ExpressionProvider.GetComparison(left, searchTerm.Operator, right);

        if (comparisonExpressions == null)
        {
            comparisonExpressions = comparisonExpression;
        }
        else if (searchTerm.LogicalConnector == "and")
        {
            comparisonExpressions = Expression.AndAlso(comparisonExpressions, comparisonExpression);
        }
        else if (searchTerm.LogicalConnector == "or")
        {
            comparisonExpressions = Expression.OrElse(comparisonExpressions, comparisonExpression);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(searchTerm.LogicalConnector);
        }
    }

    if (comparisonExpressions != null)
    {
        // x => x.Property == "Value"
        var lambdaExpression = ExpressionHelper.GetLambda<TEntity, bool>(obj, comparisonExpressions);
        // query = query.Where...
        modifiedQuery = ExpressionHelper.CallWhere(modifiedQuery, lambdaExpression);
    }

    return modifiedQuery;
}
```

Use it like:

```
var searchTerms = new List<SearchTerm>
{
    new SearchTerm { Name = "PrimaryContact", Operator = "eq", Value = "Bob" },
    new SearchTerm { Name = "SecondaryContact", Operator = "eq", Value = "Bob" },
    new SearchTerm { Name = "PrimaryContact", Operator = "eq", Value = "John", LogicalConnector = "or", }
};

IQueryable<UserEntity> query = BuildQuery<UserEntity>(modifiedQuery, searchTerms);
```

Note that there is no way in this code to explicitly set brackets, that will be implicitly set as:

```
(((A opB b) opC C) opD D)
```

Where `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` are the `SearchTerm[0]`, `SearchTerm[1]`, `SearchTerm[2]`, `SearchTerm[3]` and `opB`, `opC`, `opD` are the operators defined in `SearchTerm[1].LogicalConnector`, `SearchTerm[2].LogicalConnector`, `SearchTerm[3].LogicalConnector`.

While putting brackets is easy, choosing how to "describe" them is complex, unless you change significantly your `SearchTerm` collection (it couldn't be a "linear" array but it would need to be a tree).

P.S. I was wrong, you don't need an `ExpressionVisitor`. You need an `ExpressionVisitor` when you are trying to "merge" multiple `LambdaExpression`s that have distinct `ParameterExpression`. In this code we are able to have a single `var obj = ExpressionHelper.Parameter<TEntity>()` for all the query, so no problems merging the conditions. To make it clear: if you want to "merge" `x1 => x1.Foo == "Foo1"` with `x2 => x2.Foo == "Foo2"` then you need an `ExpressionVisitor` that replaces `x2` with `x1`, otherwise you would get a wrong query like `x1 => x1.Foo == "Foo1" || x2.Foo == "Foo2"`. In the code given we have only `x1` (that is `var obj = ExpressionHelper.Parameter<TEntity>()`), so no problem.

Comment: thank you very much for you effort @xanatos. I will definitely try this and will revert back on the result. thank you again!